# Show that the autonomous system got no periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Show that the autonomous system got no periodic solutions**

So I have this system

$$
x'=a_{11}x +a_{12}y\\
y'= a_{21}x + a_{22}y
$$

with the restriction that $a_{11}+a_{22}=1$

What I did is that I just found the eigenvalues to the matrix and then showed that the real part of the eigenvalues are always nonzero, is that enough? The answer on the solution manual is incomplete. I think it's a typo or something because the solution manual says this:

*Since $F_x+G_y\neq $ the theorem tells us that there is no periodic solutions.*

It's abit unclear. Do you know what theorem they are talking about? I guess that $F(x,y)$ corresponds to the first equation and that $G(x,y)$ is the second.

Comment: They are talking about the Bendixson criterion: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/limitations-of-the-linear-limit-cycles-and-chaos/MIT18_03SCF11_s38_3text.pdf

Comment: Also, what you have shown is also enough in this case. Linear system has closed trajectories only if the origin is center equilibrium, i.e. it has a pair of purely imaginary eigenvalues. You've ruled out this case, so no periodic solutions :)

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I thought, just wanted to make sure. I'm going to check out that link also, never hurts to know these useful theorems :)

Comment: You're welcome :)